# Timestamp conversion is invalid

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert a timestamp, but conversion is giving me 'invalid date' as result.

```
new Date("2019-01-05T13:99:99.424Z") // invalid date
```

why this date conversion is invalid?

also, what is the meaning of T13:99:99.424Z and where is this format explained. i have checked in mdn docs, but did not find details of this format.

Answer (score 2):

The date which you entered is invalid because 99 is not valid in terms of mins/secs. Try this :

```
`new Date("2019-01-05T13:10:10.424Z").`
```

The **T** doesn’t really stand for anything. It is just the separator that the [**ISO 8601**](https://www.progress.com/blogs/understanding-iso-8601-date-and-time-format) combined date-time format requires. You can read it as an abbreviation for Time.